# Webbrowser Unable to open website while internet explorer opens it

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

I have a simple windows forms application that opens a web page using `WebBrowser` and fills username and password fields and submits the form, then I just get the cookie from it and use it to download files from that site using `HttpWebRequest`:

```
    public static CookieContainer GetCookieContainer(string username, string password)
    {
        WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser(){ ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true };
        bool completed = false;
        wb.DocumentCompleted += (s, e) =>
        {
            HtmlElement el = wb.Document.GetElementById("email");
            if (el != null)
            {
                el.SetAttribute("value", username);
                wb.Document.GetElementById("password").SetAttribute("value", password);
                wb.Document.Forms["registration"].InvokeMember("submit");
            }
            else
                completed = true;
        };
        wb.Navigate("https://somesite.com/login");
        do
        {
            Application.DoEvents();
        } while (!completed);
        return GetUriCookieContainer(new Uri("https://somesite.com"));
    }
```

The above code works perfectly on my local machine and I'm able to grab CookieContainer, and use it to download the file. but when I run it on the server, I get and error popped up:

> Unable to Download / from somesite.com.
>   Unable to open this internet site. the requested site is either unavailable or can not be found. Please try again later.

[image]

I'm using windows 10, and the server is Windows server 2016.

Comment: Please don't use images, instead update question with error.

Comment: Well, I can assume that your server (where you run your winform app), do not have permission to download from that site (but your local machine does).

Comment: @SeM actually I'm just loading a webpage. and it opens without any problems in internet explorer of the server.

Comment: But can you make download action?

Comment: I don't perform, and don't need to do a download action. I just need to get the cookir container and then dispose the webbrowser